# how to delete session associated data 

Tags: php, ajax, session-timeout

say i store some **data associated with a session id** in a **database** . how do i delete the data when the session is timeout in **php**(*i do not want to fill my file sever with all junk data.*)?

is there any call back function to call in **php** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write php script

```
<?php
session_start();
$query = "DELETE FROM session_data WHERE session_id = '{$_SESSION['session_id']}'";
// in case you want to read this from ajax as json response
echo mysq_query($query) ? "true" : "false";
session_destroy();
?>
```

and access this script with ajax on uload event with JQuery

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.get('destroy_session.php', null, function(data, status) {
       // ignore result
    });
});
```

Comment: my impression is that it only destroy the session variables , not the data in the database. is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Have the user with the session report back to your database every time he makes a request. (not a new row but update his row so you wont fill your db).

Then have a cronjob or something similar clean up all sessions that have a last report timestamp older than your session timeout value.

Comment: what i concern is how to do it after the user close the window(maybe never come back.).  is it possible to do?

Comment: Then the last report back timer will be old and the cronjob will clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies as a callback per se, but maybe you could leverage the destroy handler to remove the stale database information upon explicit session termination?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: that's it , the destroy handler seem what i been looking for . thanks a lot .